# Host .net MVC4 app on localhost and get accessed from other people

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, networking, localhost, web-hosting

Here is the situation:
I made an MVC4 app with MongoDb. It is a mini social network with minimal functionality - you can follow people, post messages and see messages of people that you follow. I want to show it to my friends, so that they can use it an fill some data in the database on my computer.
I have a dynamic IP router so i did this:
when i run the app(with F5 for debugging, but it still works), it hosts on localhost:56722
i made registration in noip.com, downloaded their software. Every 5 minutes the software updates to the host if my router IP has changed. In the noip website, i made a host:
***********.myvnc.com
Host type: Port 80 redirect
IP adress - my router's ip
Port: 56722

so whenever you type **********.myvnc.com , where ********* stand for my nickname, it does redirect to my ip: port 56722

i go to my router options and make port forwarding for 
Service port: 56722
Internet port: 56722 (tried each of them swapping with 80, didn't work)

for all protocols.
Now, whenever i try to go to ***********.myvnc.com it shows the logo of M$ IIS8 and when you click it, redirects to iis website. (when i stop running the MVC and try access the host, it doesn't show it). Any idea how i can make it show my MVC application? I am really new to this stuff, this is my 1st MVC project and I've never made a website host. This is the second day I'm trying to find the solution, so i apologize if my request sounds silly :)

Comment: Go to project settings > change the port to 80,If you have skype in your PC change the setting so skype doesn't take port 80. If you use Netgear then a feature available to you is port forwarding (all model not supported it). You need to call netgear support or a guys which help you to use your router for forwarding. After this you can run your apps in all devices which have connected to same router :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't run the website in the development server, it not designed for that, and not accessible from the outside. You need to configure your website in IIS, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972
The easiest solution is to create a website with the physical path pointed to your development directory.

Also check the 'better solution' in my answer on this question: [visual web developer Web service on debug HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740156/visual-web-developer-web-service-on-debug-http-1-1-400-bad-request/13681724#13681724)

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your application to IIS and  make sure it default.Also check it is in the root folder on not or not.